# how to load dynamically texts with many languages?

Tags: android, text

I don't manage languages in the app but if the user modifies his language, texts from app have to be modify. If I use text in xml like that :

```
<TextViewCustomFont
        android:id="@+id/info_connexion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/discover"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/have_account" />
```

It works. For example, I start my app with french language then I put the app in background and I change the phone settings. I set an english language and when the app is foreground, texts are updated.

But for some reasons, I have to load dynamically texts with the following method :

```
int nameResourceID = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(key, "string", ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
if (nameResourceID == 0)
    return key;
else
    return ctx.getString(nameResourceID);
```

And with this method, it doesn't work. Off course If I start the app again, it works but it is a strange behavior because the drawables are correctly modified whereas the texts are not

How can I do that ?

Comment: is it throwing any exception?

Comment: There is no exception. It's just the wrong text which is displayed. (French text whereas the phone is english)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
public String getStringDynamically(String identfire, Context mContext) {
    try {
        int nameResourceID = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(identfire, "string", ((Activity) mContext).getPackageName());
        if (nameResourceID == 0)
            return identfire;
        else
            return mContext.getString(nameResourceID);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return identfire;
}
```